# Can't call variable from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have variable in my `AppDelegate.m` called `message`, that i would like to use in a view controller, but it's not working. I've tried this solution:

- If i import the `AppDelegate.m` into my `ViewController.m`, i get an error: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`, but if i don't import it i get this: `No known class method for selector 'message'` at this line: `self.toSort = [AppDelegate message];`. But when i import `ViewController.m` into `AppDelegate.m` i don't get the linker command error, however the other error already exists.

My `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PNChannel *myChannel;
- (void)getMessage;


AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.m"

static NSArray *_message = nil;

@implementation AppDelegate 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 //   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
    self.myChannel = [PNChannel channelWithName:currentChannel.username
         shouldObservePresence:YES];

    [self getMessage];

}   
+ (NSArray *)message
{
    if (_message)
        return _message;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate getMessage];

    return nil;
}

- (void)getMessage {

    [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {

        _message = contentArray;
        NSLog(@"test log %@", _message);   
    }];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//#import "AppDelegate.h"
//#import "AppDelegate.m"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //[appDelegate getMessage];

    self.toSort = [AppDelegate message];
    [self getMessageList];

}
```

I'm sure i did some beginner mistake, but i can't figure it out. The "test log" works, so i think i have to call it in a different way.

Already tried this, but also get an error because message is not a property.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *variableTest = appDelegate.message;
NSLog(@"TEST : %@",variableTest);
```

UPDATE: I've tried this, but the test log shows null, so something is still wrong.

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PNChannel *myChannel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *message;
- (void)getMessage;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
 //   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.myChannel = [PNChannel channelWithName:currentChannel.username
         shouldObservePresence:YES];

    [self getMessage];

    }
    return YES;
}

+ (NSArray *)message
{
    if (self.message)
        return self.message;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate getMessage];

    return nil;
}

- (void)getMessage {

    [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {

         self.message = contentArray;

         NSLog(@"dev log %@", self.message);
    }];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSArray *variableTest = appDelegate.message;
    NSLog(@"TEST : %@",variableTest);


}
```

**My try based on o Pi's answer:**

```
@interface MessageHistoryData : NSObject {
    NSArray *yourData;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *yourData;
+(MessageHistoryData *)getInstance;

@end
```

---

```
#import "MessageHistoryData.h"

@implementation MessageHistoryData @synthesize yourData;
static MessageHistoryData *instance =nil;
+(MessageHistoryData *)getInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(instance==nil) {
            instance= [MessageHistoryData new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

@end
```

in my ViewController.m (MessageHistoryData is imported into the .h)

-(void)setupArray {

```
[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:my_channel from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:NO withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {

        MessageHistoryData *data = [MessageHistoryData getInstance];

        data.yourData = contentArray;

        NSLog(@"Dev log2 %@", data.yourData);


}];
```

}

Comment: You need to import the header files (.h) and not the implementation/methods files (.m)

Comment: The ViewController.h into the AppDelegate.m and, and AppDelegate.h into the ViewController.h?

Comment: #import AppDelegate.h should go in the ViewController.h or ViewController.m depending on your needs. Also, in response to your update, message is more than likely nill because requestFullHistoryForChannel looks to be asynchronous. You can either add a completionBlock on getMessage and use the value once it has returned or just call requestFullHistoryForChannel: in ViewController.m and use the value once it has returned.

Comment: It's working fine inside the AppDelegate, i can log it. It will be nil in the ViewController. Sorry if misunderstood your last sentence, it's because the lack of my english skills.

Comment: @Jonathan I called [appDelegate getMessage]; before the log in the ViewController, but the log still the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up a sample project to verify that this works.

In the AppDelegate.h file, publicly declare the `message` property and `-getMessage` method:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *message;

- (void)getMessage;

@end
```

In the AppDelegate.m file, implement your methods as you normally would (I explicitly set the property for the sake of example):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    return YES;
}

- (void)getMessage {
    self.message = @"This is a message";
}

@end
```

In your `ViewController.m` file, you should import the AppDelegate header, and you should be free to access the properties:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"The delegate's message is: %@", delegate.message);  // Logs "The delegate's message is: (null)"
    [delegate getMessage];
    NSLog(@"The delegate's message is: %@", delegate.message);  // Logs "The delegate's message is: This is a message"
}

@end
```

If the above doesn't work, you should test your `PubNub` class and ensure it's behavior is predictable.

I don't recommend EVER storing information in your AppDelegate, as that makes the class responsible for doing more than just being your application's delegate with the system. Information like this should be stored in a dedicated store, or made available through a custom `PubNub` subclass that is accessed as a singleton (if there's no global state to be managed!) or an instance by instance basis.

Let me know if you need any clarification or if the solution above doesn't work for you.

EDIT: Singleton Suggestion

As per my comment, here is one way to handle sharing network data across view controllers

```
@interface NetworkClient : PubNub

@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString *message;

/**
 *  Returns a shared network client to be used throughout the app
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedClient;  

- (void)configureWithChannel:(PNChannel*)channel;
- (void)clearChannel;

- (void)getMessagesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *, PNChannel *, PNDate *, PNDate *, PNError *))

@end
```

Where sharedInstance uses the [technique described here](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) to setup your instance. From there, you can access the client using `[NetworkClient sharedClient]` and retrieve any data through the instance methods or properties on the client.

I'm also guessing you are new to singletons or iOS in general, so I'm going to recommend you read [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/singletons.html) about using singletons, and the blog [objc.io](http://objc.io) to familiarize yourself with some best practices that will absolutely make your life easier.

Comment: I don't need to store it in the AppDelegate. This solution based on another question. The point is that i need to access the data from the `contentArray` in several view controllers. However it's data is not static, so if it has new contents i must be able to update the `message` array. So in this case AppDelegate is a really bad idea?

Comment: I would create a singleton class that manages the `contentArray` and access it through that class itself. I'll update my answer with some psudo code

Comment: Yes, you are right, i'm a rookie in programming. I'm checking the suggested resources, but one thing is not clear. As a first step, I need to create a new PubNub class file with the updated code, and also the singleton from the tutorial?

Comment: You need to create a PubNub subclass, and use the `dispatch_once` code  in your `sharedClient` method. The `dispatch_once` is a thread-safe way of setting up a single instance of an object. The object created in the block should be saved to a static variable within the class, and returned for every succeeding call to `sharedClient`

Comment: `- (void)getMessagesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *messages, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *date, PNDate *dateTwo, PNError *error));` Something is not proper with this line, i'm getting _Expected identifier_ error.

Comment: I've read the objc.io article and it was a super helpful, thanks! i think i should use dependency injection. what do you think, it's much harder to implement? i've checked some articles about it, but didn't find a good example.

Comment: I'm not sure, the project is yours. I believe I answered the above question sufficiently, and would really appreciate it if you accept my answer for the question.

Comment: I would be the happier, if i could accept it. Your answer is useful, this is the reason why i gave +1. I will try to do it again, but please check my comment that i wrote under your answer 2 days ago about the error i experienced. I really appreciate your help and don't want to be disrespectful, i'm trying to solve this problem a couple of days ago so you can imagine how much i want to accept it.

Comment: I'm also not trying to be disrespectful, but I don't have your code, nor the time to debug it. I only wrote the above interface as an example. I wish you the best of luck to figure out the error, and what solution works for you.

Answer (score 2):

First there is no need to declare the variable static since `[UIApplication sharedAppliction] delegate]` will always be the same instance. So just declare a property in the `AppDelegate.h` file and use that.

**in AppDelegat.h**

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *message;
```

**in AppDelegate.m use it like this:**

```
self.message
```

And in your view controller import the .h and do:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray *arr = appDelegate.message;
```

Comment: Peter, i've updated my question with my try based on your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Please check it, maybe i did something different.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but when you do [self getMessage]; in a instance method(-) self is bound to the instance and not the class object. Sending messages to self that can only be handled by the class object should only be done in other class methods within the same class. Easiest is just to change the (+) to a (-) on the method implementation. Does this line get printed: NSLog(@"dev log %@", self.message); If still no luck put a breakpoint in your view controller and check so app delegate valuable is not nil or something.

Comment: Yes, that log get printed and the value in the AppDelegate wasn't a nil.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put public variables into your header file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getMessage` method uses an async call to get the messages. If you can't retrieve it in a sync way maybe you should call `getMessage` as soon as possible.

Better yet you could also use blocks to return the messages async:

```
+ (void)asyncMessage:(void(^)(NSArray * message))callbackBlock
{
    if (_message)
    {
        callbackBlock(_message);
        return;
    }

    [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {

        _message = contentArray;
        callbackBlock(_message);
        NSLog(@"test log %@", _message);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

never import .m class in xcode because this throws cling: error.
if u want to `NSArray` defined in `appdelegate` to use later in your any view controller,there may be many approaches.some of them are-

1. initilise your array in `appdelegate.h` like this

   ```
   @property(nonatmoic,retain)nsarray *message;
   ```

   then in your `appdelegate.m` class in `didfinishlaunchingwithOptions` method allocate memory to this    array-

   ```
   message=[[nsarray alloc]initwithobjects:@"abc"];
   ```

   then in your view controller make object of app delegate and access this property like this-

   ```
   NSLog(@"array is %@",appdelegateobject.message);
   ```
2. In your first question you trying to return this array by class method,but in appdelegate you returning nil,so how will u get this message array,

Answer (score 0):

Take the message variable and paste it into the .h then delete it from the .m

Answer (score 0):

You can not import a implement file in your implement file like this.

```
AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.m"  // This is the reason causes error.
```

I made this errors before....

Modify like this easily fix this problem.

```
AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to properties the message array to make public

`AppDelegate.h`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *message;
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: In my `ViewController`?

Comment: NO..Check my updated answer.At App Delegate .h you need to properties and at .m synthesize..

Comment: You don't need to synthesise properties anymore.. since like 2 years ago :) It auto synthesises to _message.